# ¿Por qué un árbol binario de búsqueda es más rápido que cuando se va eliminando la mitad de un array (ordenado) y se sigue buscando en la otra mitad?

Tags: algoritmos, busqueda

Me surge la duda, por que los dos métodos mencionados en la pregunta los encuentro muy similares.

Comment: A la hora de buscar, ambos iguales de rápidos si no me equivoco. El problema está a la hora de insertar o eliminar O(n). Mover datos en un array para mantenerlo ordenado es más caro, en un arbol binario todas las operaciones siempre son O(log n), lo cual significa muchísimas menos operaciones cuanto más grande es la cantidad de datos. En resumen, si solo vas a buscar, da un poco igual (Especialmente si el array está en memoria), si necesitas insertar/eliminar, siempre es mejor un BST (Binary Search Tree)

Comment: En ambos descartas la mitad de los elementos en cada comparación. No parecen ser diferentes en cuanto a busquedas.

Comment: ¿Por qué piensas que es más rápido el árbol binario?